# DOMDocument Preserve ASCII Encoding?

Tags: php, xml, encoding, ascii, domdocument

Okay, I have a file named "**temp.xml**" with about 100 entries. Here's an example of a subentry..

```
<title>&#169; 2008 Some Company</title>
```

Now, I want to get the EXACT contents within the "**title**" but by doing...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('temp.xml');
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $node) {
echo $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

I get...

> ```
> Â© 2008 Some Company
> ```

And I want...

> ```
> &#169; 2008 Some Company
> ```

Php is converting the ASCII characters and I want to have them intact. I'm googling this for more than two hours now to no avail...

Comment: 'Â' has character code 195. i can't guess out why you have that character there also.

Comment: if the php page writes output to browser as webpage. definitely you won't see "&#169;", because this is html entity, so browser will show it as character

Comment: I know the browser will display it as a character but I want to save it to the database...

Comment: what is the encoding of your xml file?

Comment: i guess the answer is here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=803529

Comment: the xml file has the first line indicating that it is encoded in utf8. however, the editor programme actually saves it as ansi or something

Comment: Okay, forget the Â... It was generated by using the mysql_real_escape_string() but the copyright sign still does not display as &#169; when I view the source of the php output in the browser... The xml encoding (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>)is set to UTF-8 and both, the .xml and the .php is is saved in notepad++ with encoding set to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seems like the connection to MySql with XAMPP was not done in UTF-8... so here's what solved my problem...

```
$link2 = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link2); //Set the connection to UTF-8
mysql_select_db('mydb') or die( "Unable to select database");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('temp.xml');
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $node) {
$title = $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$query = "INSERT INTO sb_temp (id, title) VALUES ('', '$title')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
}
```

I simply set the mysql connection like... mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link2); and now the data is saved as is. Otherwise the "©" sign for example was saved as "Â©". Thanks for helping anyway :]